# NSScrollView not working on Mountain Lion

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion

Im testing my app on Mountain Lion, and now nothing shows up in my document view after i do "setDocumentView" on my scrollView. If I remove "setDocumentView" the subviews of docView show  up, but obviously I am then unable to control the scrolling.

Any idea what they changed or why this is?

Comment: Now that Mountain Lion isn't under NDA anymore, did you find a solution to this problem? I think I've got the same problem.

Comment: Nope, havent found a solution. Wouldn't hurt if you upvote this question. Please respond if you find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I was working on an IKImageView in a NSScrollView myself for some hours now. Adjusting the size of the document was not enough at all. But it works also fine under Mountain Lion. All I had to do was:

```
scroller.hasVerticalScroller = YES;
scroller.hasHorizontalScroller = YES;
```